# Winstone: could not find Factory: javax.faces.context.FacesContextFactory

Tags: jsf, winstone

I'm not able to publish JSF2 application on Winstone server.

Server is configured fine and when I remove

```
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
```

from web.xml, it starts normally:

[image]

But when I try to start indew.xhtml, server reports:

[image]

Part of my **web.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
         xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" 
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" 
         id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>PIA</display-name>
  <session-config>
    <session-timeout>60</session-timeout>
  </session-config>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <context-param>
    <description>State saving method: 'client' or 'server'.</description>
    <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
    <param-value>client</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt.localizationContext</param-name>
    <param-value>resources.application</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX</param-name>
    <param-value>.xhtml</param-value>
  </context-param>
</web-app>
```

---

**Update**: I've tried `winstone 1.0.0.jar` and it reports this:

[image]

But I have `slf4j-api-1.6.4.jar` and `slf4j-log4j12-1.6.4.jar` in my WEB-INF\lib folder...
Where should be a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your `web.xml` to explicitly register the listener which is supposed to configure the JSF factories.

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Another possible solution is to remove the `<load-on-startup>` from the `FacesServlet`, but I have never used Winstone so I can't guarantee if that would work on that server.

This workaround is usually not mandatory in decent servers, but in poor servers it is. For more background information, see also [could not find Factory: javax.faces.context.FacesContextFactory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7886035/could-not-find-factory-javax-faces-context-facescontextfactory).

---

**Update** as per the comments, after adding the listener the exception disappeared, but now a `Error instantiating listener class: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener` appears without any stacktrace. The swallowing of the stacktrace seems to be a Winstone bug which was [fixed](http://code.google.com/p/winstone/source/browse/trunk/winstone/DONE.txt?r=102) in [1.0.0](http://code.google.com/p/winstone/downloads/detail?name=winstone-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar). Give it a try, it should now show the real cause of the problem.

---

**Update 2** as per the question update, the real cause seems to be a `NoClassDefFoundError` on `org.slf4j.loggerFactory`. This is however not used by Mojarra in any way. The stacktrace also indicates that this is happening before loading any listeners. In other words, this is likely a different problem, releated to Winstone. Apparently Winstone *itself* needs that library. Add it to the runtime classpath of Winstone instead of the `/WEB-INF/lib`.

Comment: Thank you Balusc, but now it says: `[Winstone 2011/12/09 16:29:01] - Error instantiating listener class: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener`....:/

Comment: What's the root cause then? Are you using Mojarra or MyFaces? I somehow assumed Mojarra...

Comment: OK, tell about the root cause. This message is just an informal message which tells that **an exception** has occurred during creating the listener. You need to lookup this exception and tell about it. By the way, how about removing the `<load-on-startup>`? In *theory* this might work.

Comment: I do not know, whenever I try to start xhtml which includes JSF. I'm even not able to deploy YOURS usingDatatables.war example. The same problem ... First page is ok, but if I choose next page with JSF, the problem is happening

Comment: If I remove it, everything is fine UNTIL starting of first page with JSF :)

Comment: Well.. Blame Winstone :/ I have by the way found this bug fix report: http://code.google.com/p/winstone/source/browse/trunk/winstone/DONE.txt?r=102 It seems that the suppressing of the exception during instantiation of the listener is been fixed in a newer Winstone version 1.0.0. You should then get the real exception in the logs.

Comment: Thank you, I'll wait for newest version :) In fact I don't need it now, but it is required in school :)

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/winstone/downloads/detail?name=winstone-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar The project itself however seems to be dead. I'd rather choose another, more decent server.