# The listener "com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener" is already configured for this context. The duplicate definition has been ignored

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, jsf-2, web.xml

i am getting the following info when running my application:

```
The listener "com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener" is already configured for this context. The duplicate definition has been ignored.
```

and i want to know what is the cause for such error ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First of all, this is a **warning**, not an **error**. The difference is pretty huge. The web application can just continue to run. Warnings are merely to inform the developer about circumstances which are different from expected/natural behaviours which does not necessarily break the functionality. This is very useful for the case that the developer was not aware about the configuration and/or its consequences.

That listener is usually auto-registered by JSF TLD file and the `ServletContainerInitializer`. You can get this warning message if you have actually *explicitly* registered the very same listener in your webapp's `web.xml`.

This warning does not harm. It is basically telling you that you don't need to explicitly register the listener in your webapp's `web.xml` for the particular target servlet container. You could safely remove the `<listener>` entry in question from the webapp's `web.xml`.

However, explicit registration is mandatory in some circumstances such as when the webapp is intented to be deployed to a buggy servlet container which does not properly load the listener from the TLD and/or does not support the `ServletContainerInitializer`.

#### See also:

- [could not find Factory: javax.faces.context.FacesContextFactory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7886035/could-not-find-factory-javax-faces-context-facescontextfactory)