# Configuration of com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, mojarra

I'm reviewing a current JSF project where the `web.xml` configuration contains:

- the FacesServlet (configured on `*.xhtml`)
- the `com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener`

I'm using JSF 2.2 and Mojarra implementation.

I'm confused about the `ConfigureListener`. Is this class needed in the configuration? What is the goal of this class? I couldn't find any information and the class has almost no javadoc.

If I remove this configuration, everything seem to work the same way. Thus I guess that the `ConfigureListener` could or should be removed but I am not sure.

Comment: Look for this http://www.coderanch.com/t/428264/JSF/java/function-listener-sun-faces-config

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The `ConfigureListener` is normally automatically registered via `/META-INF/jsf_core.tld` file of Mojarra implementation JAR file. Additionally, the `ConfigureListener` is explicitly registered via a Servlet 3.0 `ServletContainerInitializer` in order to workaround an old GlassFish v3 bug (note: v3, not 3.0.x, thus really that one first GF3 version ever).

There exist situations wherein the auto-registration via `.tld` file is insufficient. The well known one is when the webapp is deployed to [Jetty](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/). This is explained in detail in this Q&A: [could not find Factory: javax.faces.context.FacesContextFactory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7886035/could-not-find-factory-javax-faces-context-facescontextfactory).

Also, as mentioned before and in that detailed answer, GlassFish v3 has a bug wherein the TLD file is scanned too late and thus JSF couldn't do its necessary initialization thing at the right moment. You'd then need to explicitly register the `ConfigureListener` in webapp's `web.xml`.

But if it works for you when it's not explicitly registered in `web.xml`, then just keep it out. Less noise in `web.xml` is better. But if you happen to possibly deploy to a container sensitive to the mentioned problem (so when your webapp is actually a publicly distributed one and you have no control over choice of target container), then you'd better keep it in "for the case that".

---

**Update**: It appears that Tomcat 8.x shows buggy behavior when this entry is enabled in `web.xml`: this listener will actually be executed twice instead of only once. The consequence is disastrous: among others, all JSF event listeners will be registered twice and component libraries will be loaded twice. This leads only to conflicts during runtime. In other words, when deploying to Tomcat, make sure that this entry is removed from `web.xml`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I realized that the `FacesServlet` is actually configured on `/*.xhtml`. I updated the question.

Comment: You're welcome. I'd doublecheck that. This is namely illegal syntax. I updated the Q with right one.

Comment: You are right (again). Sorry I checked too fast. I have `*.xhtml`.

Comment: With ICEFaces 3.3.0 and tomcat >= 7.0.42, declaring this listener in web.xml causes a specific icefaces component to be added twice with same id on each page, thus causing an error. See this forum post : http://www.icesoft.org/JForum/posts/list/22121.page

Comment: I can confirm that the same buggy behavior, where a config listener is created twice, also happens on WebLogic 12.2.1.3. Removing the listener from _web.xml_ resolves it.