# Clarify Some of the JSF questions

Tags: jsf, jsf-1.2

1. Can we change the name of faces-config.xml file or it should be the same name ?
2. In jsf 1.2 , default suffix is .jsp and jsf 2.0 default suffix is .xhtml? Can we have a default suffix as .jsf
3. What is the use of  the below line?

   `<listener>
       <listener-class>com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener</listener-class>
   </listener> here`
4. How to get a managed bean name, scope and request url programatically?
5. I have 1000 records in my database but i just want to show the records from 100 to 200 (in  a jsf datatable? How can i do that?
6. How a request works in jsf?
7. What is re-render and rendered attributes?  what is the use of those?
8. difference between f:param and f:attribute? where and when we use those?
9. Do we use none scope? in what scenario it will be used?

Comment: can you please let me know..why it was downvoted. so that i can make necessary changes to my question?

Comment: I think i can't get answer to above questions .. as this was already downvoted. disappointed :( :(

Comment: I have edited my question as much as.. but still gets downvoted and no answers..

Comment: You are asking tons of questions and most of them need you first to read about this technology. You don't demonstrate any effort in answering by yourself or searching.

Answer (score 2):

> Can we change the name of faces-config.xml file

Yes, but then it ceases to be a `faces-config.xml` file. It's hard to see why you're even asking.

> or it should be the same name?

If you want it to work, yes.

> In jsf 1.2 , default suffix is .jsp and jsf 2.0 default suffix is .xhtml? Can we have a default suffix as .jsf

Yes.

> What is the use of the below line?

```
<listener> <listener-class>com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener</listener-class> </listener> here
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20264804/207421), which you could have found for yourself.

> How to get a managed bean name, scope and request url programatically?

The name of a managed bean is fixed when you compile it, so I don't know why you're even asking. I don't know what 'get a scope' means. You can get the request URL from the `ExternalContext.`

> I have 1000 records in my database but i just want to show the records from 100 to 200 (in a jsf datatable? How can i do that?

With a LIMIT clause in your SQL.

> How a request works in jsf?

Far too broad to answer here.

> What is re-render and rendered attributes?

`reRender` is part of RichFaces. `rendered` is part of JSF.

> what is the use of those?

These things are documented. There's no need to ask about things like that here.

> difference between f:param and f:attribute?

Ditto.

> where and when we use those?

Ditto.

> Do we use none scope?

If you need it.

> in what scenario it will be used?

When you don't need any other scope.

This questions are pretty frivolous. You could have more usefully spent the time doing some research of your own. Don't let me stop you.