# Unable to load servlet listener class: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener

Tags: maven, jsf, apache-tomee

I'm using **apache-tomee-jaxrs-1.7.1** and I'm trying to deploy with maven 3 getting this error:

> Unable to load servlet listener class: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener:

These are my dependencies in pom.xml:

```
  ...
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax</groupId>
      <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
      <version>6.0</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
      <artifactId>jstl-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.2</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.openjpa</groupId>
      <artifactId>openjpa</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  ...
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply get rid of the in the exception mentioned `<listener>` entry in webapp's `web.xml`.

TomEE ships with MyFaces, not Mojarra. That Mojarra-specific `<listener>` entry in `web.xml` is usually auto-included by some IDEs trying to be smarter than they are and/or left behind in poor quality open source projects. Be careful on them. That explicit registration is unnecessary on decent containers. See also a.o. [Configuration of com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20264083/configuration-of-com-sun-faces-config-configurelistener).

Comment: You are completely right. I added `<listener-class>org.apache.myfaces.webapp.StartupServletContextListener</listener-class>` in *web.xml* and now works! Sorry for this dummy question, thanks a lot.

Comment: That one should also not have been necessary. Those listeners are supposed to be auto-registered without any additional configuration. This would only fail in buggy containers (as mentioned in that link), but as far as I experienced, a regular TomEE container doesn't have this problem.