# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find backup for factory javax.faces.context.FacesContextFactory

Tags: maven, jsf, apache-tomee

I'm getting the java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find backup for factory javax.faces.context.FacesContextFactory. when I deploy my webapp as a .war.  Does anyone have an idea where to begin looking for the root cause of this problem? The application runs as expected in the Eclipse IDE, but when exported as a war for deploying on the publicly available stand-alone TomEE environment, it fails.

Many thanks.

My configuration:
Apache TomEE - WebProfile 1.6.0.2
JSF 2.2.7 (com.sun.faces)(Mojarra lib 2.2.0) <-- This may be a problem? But why does the app run in the Eclipse environment but not the stand-alone TomEE?

Maven 4.0.0

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find backup for factory javax.faces.context.FacesContextFactory. 
    javax.faces.FactoryFinder$FactoryManager.getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:1004)
    javax.faces.FactoryFinder.getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:316)
    javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.init(FacesServlet.java:302)
    org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBValve.invoke(OpenEJBValve.java:45)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:315)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

The web.xml:

```
<web-app 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" 
    id="WebApp_ID" 
    version="3.0">
  <display-name>ProjName</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>login.xhtml</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
    <param-value>Development</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_SKIP_COMMENTS</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
  </context-param>
   <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.INTERPRET_EMPTY_STRING_SUBMITTED_VALUES_AS_NULL</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.faces.forceLoadConfiguration</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
  </context-param>

  <context-param>
    <description>State saving method: 'client' or 'server' (=default). See JSF Specification 2.5.2</description>
    <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
    <param-value>client</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt.localizationContext</param-name>
    <param-value>resources.application</param-value>
  </context-param>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.faces</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

The jars that are exported in the .war WEB-INF/lib directory:

```
WEB-INF/lib/javax.faces.jar
WEB-INF/lib/javax.faces-api-2.2.jar
WEB-INF/lib/jsf-api-2.2.7.jar
WEB-INF/lib/jsf-impl-2.2.7.jar
WEB-INF/lib/poi-3.10-FINAL.jar
WEB-INF/lib/commons-codec-1.5.jar
WEB-INF/lib/poi-ooxml-3.10-FINAL.jar
WEB-INF/lib/poi-ooxml-schemas-3.10-FINAL.jar
WEB-INF/lib/xmlbeans-2.3.0.jar
WEB-INF/lib/stax-api-1.0.1.jar
WEB-INF/lib/dom4j-1.6.1.jar
WEB-INF/lib/xml-apis-1.0.b2.jar
WEB-INF/lib/cxf-bundle-jaxrs-2.7.11.jar
WEB-INF/lib/woodstox-core-asl-4.2.1.jar
WEB-INF/lib/stax2-api-3.1.4.jar
WEB-INF/lib/xmlschema-core-2.1.0.jar
WEB-INF/lib/geronimo-javamail_1.4_spec-1.7.1.jar
WEB-INF/lib/wsdl4j-1.6.3.jar
WEB-INF/lib/jaxb-impl-2.1.13.jar
WEB-INF/lib/jetty-server-8.1.14.v20131031.jar
WEB-INF/lib/jetty-continuation-8.1.14.v20131031.jar
WEB-INF/lib/jetty-http-8.1.14.v20131031.jar
WEB-INF/lib/jetty-io-8.1.14.v20131031.jar
WEB-INF/lib/jetty-util-8.1.14.v20131031.jar
WEB-INF/lib/jetty-security-8.1.14.v20131031.jar
WEB-INF/lib/slf4j-api-1.7.6.jar
WEB-INF/lib/geronimo-servlet_3.0_spec-1.0.jar
WEB-INF/lib/javax.ws.rs-api-2.0-m10.jar
WEB-INF/lib/postgresql-9.3-1101-jdbc41.jar
WEB-INF/lib/commons-httpclient-3.1.jar
WEB-INF/lib/commons-logging-1.0.4.jar
WEB-INF/lib/hamcrest-all-1.3.jar
WEB-INF/lib/junit-4.11.jar
WEB-INF/lib/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar
WEB-INF/lib/httpclient-4.3.3.jar
WEB-INF/lib/httpcore-4.3.2.jar
WEB-INF/lib/commons-dbcp2-2.0.jar
WEB-INF/lib/commons-pool2-2.2.jar
WEB-INF/lib/mockito-core-1.9.5.jar
WEB-INF/lib/objenesis-1.0.jar
```

Answer (score 3):

I resolved this by removing the  parameter from the web.xml file.

```
 <listener>
    <listener-class>com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
```

Removing the above text, rebuilding, exporting the war from Eclipse and deploying with the Tomcat Web Application Manager UI resolved the problem.  Apparently, one of the jsf jars has this code built-in since http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0 .  I don't know this to be a fact, but read it in [could not find Factory: javax.faces.context.FacesContextFactory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7886035/could-not-find-factory-javax-faces-context-facescontextfactory?rq=1). The difference here being that I removed the parameter instead of adding it.

Comment: Of course the reasons are to get the project to run, however misguided following tutorials or various posts on Stack Overflow. Are you saying that I can remove the maven dependencies for JSF and the project should run on TomEE?

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this issue by removing the web.xml file and put these two methods in the Spring configuration file.

```
@Bean
public ServletContextInitializer servletContextCustomizer() {
        return new ServletContextInitializer() {
            @Override
            public void onStartup(ServletContext sc) throws ServletException {
sc.setInitParameter(Constants.ContextParams.THEME, "bootstrap");
sc.setInitParameter(Constants.ContextParams.FONT_AWESOME, "true");
sc.setInitParameter(ProjectStage.PROJECT_STAGE_PARAM_NAME,ProjectStage.Development.name());
sc.setInitParameter("com.sun.faces.forceLoadConfiguration", "true");
sc.setInitParameter("contextConfigLocation", "test");
    }
  };
}
@Bean
public ServletRegistrationBean servletRegistrationBean() {
    FacesServlet servlet = new FacesServlet();
    ServletRegistrationBean registration = new ServletRegistrationBean(servlet, "*.jsf");
    registration.setName("Faces Servlet");
    registration.addUrlMappings("*.jsf");
    registration.setMultipartConfig(new MultipartConfigElement((String) null));
    registration.setEnabled(true);
    registration.setLoadOnStartup(1);
    return registration;
}
```